# C: Segmentation fault when trying to create a list using malloc

Tags: c, list, segmentation-fault, malloc

I'm trying to create a list using malloc, the program gets integers that are input by the user, and it exits when the user inputs 0. However I'm getting the Segmentation fault (core dumped) error and I haven't been able to spot the problem. Things I have tried include adding the "liberar" method to free the memory but it doesn't work either. Thanks!

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

struct list1 {
   int val;
   struct list1 * sig;
};

typedef struct list1 i;

void main() {
   i * aux, * cabeza;
   int entrada;

   cabeza = NULL;

   while(1) {
      aux = (i*)malloc(sizeof(i));
      scanf("%d\n",entrada);
      if(entrada==0){
          exit(0);
      }
      aux->val = entrada;
      aux->sig  = cabeza;
      cabeza = aux;
      liberar(cabeza);
   }

   aux = cabeza;

   while(aux) {
      printf("%d\n", aux->val);
      aux = aux->sig ;
   }
}

int liberar(struct list1* cabez)
{   
    struct list1 *temp;
    while (cabez != NULL)
    {
       temp = cabez;
       cabez = cabez->sig;
       free(temp);
    }

}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d\n",entrada);` -->  `scanf("%d", &entrada);` and `i * cabeza = NULL;` cabeza need initialize. and `liberar(cabeza);` remove.

Comment: `i` is a terrible name for a type alias...

Comment: YOu allocate space for aux, assign aux to cabeza (these are just pointers, free the space pointed to by cabeza (and aux), then use aux again, even though what it points to has been freed. That isn't going to work

Comment: 1) english variable names are easier to understand: entrada == input? cabeza == ???
2) malloc() can fail. you have to check the result.
3) you allocate the list element for aux before you know that you need it. In the case of (entrada==0) you will leak memory (assuming later you do something other than exit(0))

Comment: How are you developing your code? do You have an IDE? If you don't, get one. When you do, learn how to use the debugger. Set breakpoints, examine variables & this sort of thing gets much easier to solve.  Welcome abord & happy coding !

Comment: int liberar(struct list1* cabez) should return void

Comment: And activate warnings in the compiler, e.g with gcc use at least: gcc -O2 -W -Wall -g

Comment: You're list never has more than one valid node, and that only until you call `liberar()`. After that, the caller's pointer `cabeza` is indeterminate, yet you continue to use it.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Yes! that was the mistake, I just added the & and removed the method, thank you!

Comment: "Things I have tried include adding the "liberar" method to free the memory". If you're getting segfaults, adding more frees is pretty much certain to make things worse! Work out where the misuse is happening first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correcting all things from the comments (and a few unsaid things) you get this source:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<assert.h>

typedef struct List {
    int val;
    struct List * next;
} List;

void list_free(List * list)
{   
    while (list != NULL)
    {
        List *temp = list;
        list = list->next;
        free(temp);
    }
}

int main() {
    List * aux, * result;
    int input;

    result = NULL;

    while(1) {
        scanf("%d",&input);
        if(input == 0){
            break;
        }
        aux = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List));
        assert(aux != NULL);
        aux->val = input;
        aux->next  = result;
        result = aux;
    }

    aux = result;

    printf("Result =\n");

    while(aux) {
        printf("%d\n", aux->val);
        aux = aux->next;
    }

    list_free(result);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can tighten things up (but this works OK).  For example, `List *result = NULL;` instead of separating the declaration and the initialization.  The variable `aux` should be declared inside the `while (1)` loop.  Additionally, that loop should be `while (scanf("%d", &input) == 1)` without the test and break inside the loop.  The result printing code could be `for (List *aux = result; aux != NULL; aux = aux->next) { printf("%d\n", aux->val); }`, again limiting the scope of this second `aux` variable.  The C standard always shows a space between `#include` and the header name; you should too.